# Can't find variable: queriesString - React Native Context

Tags: react-native, react-context

The app is for looking up information about product from an api, either by article or ean code.

User can input Article code or EAN in TextInput or scan a barcode and get the information about the product from the api.

The problem I'm having is I'm not able to pass the search queries from the Textinput to the queriesString in the Context Provider.

This is the error code I'm getting:

> ReferenceError: can't find variable: queriesString

For what I'm able to find out the code should work, but since its my first app in react native I'm most likely missing something.

App

```js
    App.js
    
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
    import HomeScreen from "./app/screens/HomeScreen";
    import ScannerScreen from "./app/screens/ScannerScreen";
    import { queriesContext } from "./app/global/queriesContext";
    
    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    
    export default function App() {
        return (
            <>
                <queriesContext.Provider value={{ queriesString: "123456789" }}>
                    {console.log(queriesString + " - From App")}
                    <NavigationContainer>
                        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
                            <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
                            <Stack.Screen name='Scanner' component={ScannerScreen} />
                        </Stack.Navigator>
                    </NavigationContainer>
                </queriesContext.Provider>
            </>
        );
    }
```

HomeScreen

```js
    HomeScreen.js
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView, Platform, TextInput, Button, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard } from "react-native";
    import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import ProductScreen from "../global/GetData";
    import { queriesContext } from "../global/queriesContext";
    
    export default function HomeScreen() {
        const [queriesString, setQueriesString] = useContext(queriesContext);
        const [queries, setQueries] = useState(queriesString);
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        const handleSearch = () => {
            setQueriesString(queries);
        };
        ProductScreen();
        //console.log(useState.q);
    
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                <SafeAreaView style={styles.MainScreen}>
                    <ProductScreen />
                    <TextInput style={styles.TextField} editable={true} maxLength='30' numberOfLines='1' placeholder='Art no.' keyboardType='numeric' onChange={(text) => setQueries(text)} />
                    <Button color='red' title='Search' onPress={handleSearch} />
                    <View style={styles.BarcodeBox}>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Scanner")}>
                            <Image style={styles.BarcodeImage} source={require("../assets/barcode.png")} />
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        MainScreen: {.............},
    });
```

ScannerScreen

Not complete since i can't get to pass the value from HomeScreen to context.

```js
    ScannerScreen.js    
    import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { Text, View, Alert, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
    import { BarCodeScanner } from "expo-barcode-scanner";
    
    export default function ScannerScreen() {
        const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
        const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
        useEffect(() => {
            const getBarCodeScannerPermissions = async () => {
                const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
                setHasPermission(status === "granted");
            };
    
            getBarCodeScannerPermissions();
        }, []);
    
        const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
            setScanned(true);
            Alert.alert("Strekkode", data, [{ text: "Yes", onPress: () => setScanned(false) }, { text: "No" }]);
        };
    
        if (hasPermission === null) {
            return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
        }
        if (hasPermission === false) {
            return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
        }
        return (
            <BarCodeScanner onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned} style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.container]}>
                <View style={styles.layerTop} />
                <View style={styles.layerCenter}>
                    <View style={styles.layerLeft} />
                    <View style={styles.focused} />
                    <View style={styles.layerRight} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.layerBottom} />
            </BarCodeScanner>
        );
    }
    const opacity = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)";
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "column",
        },
        layerTop: {
            flex: 2,
            backgroundColor: opacity,
        },
        layerCenter: {
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "row",
        },
        layerLeft: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: opacity,
        },
        focused: {
            flex: 10,
        },
        layerRight: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: opacity,
        },
        layerBottom: {
            flex: 2,
            backgroundColor: opacity,
        },
    });
```

GetData

```js
    GetData.js
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView, Platform, TextInput, Button, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard } from "react-native";
    
    import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { queriesContext } from "./queriesContext";
    
    export default ProductScreen = () => {
        const [queriesString] = useContext(queriesContext);
        const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        const [isPromotion, setPromotion] = useState(false);
        const [data, setData] = useState({
            results: [BEFORE API IS CALLED NOT...],
        });
        console.log(queriesString + " - From GetData");
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(
                "SERVER.........",
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "x-algolia-agent": "Algolia for JavaScript (4.13.1); Browser; JS Helper (3.10.0)",
                        "x-algolia-application-id": "***********",
                        "x-algolia-api-key": "************************",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        requests: [
                            {
                                indexName: "prod_products",
                                params: "query=" + queriesString,
                            },
                        ],
                    }),
                }
            )
                .then((respnse) => respnse.json())
                .then((json) => setData(json), console.log(data))
                .catch((error) => console.error(error))
                .finally(() => setLoading(false));
        }, []);
        //console.log(data);
        //console.log(queryString);
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                <SafeAreaView style={styles.ProductScreen}>
                    <View style={styles.LogoBox}>
                        <Image source={require("../assets/Logo.png")} />
                        <Image
                            style={styles.ProductImage}
                            resizeMode='contain'
                            source={
                                isLoading
                                    ? require("../assets/fallback_266x266.png")
                                    : {
                                            uri: "https://................/" + data.results[0].hits[0].picture.product,
                                      }
                            }
                        />
                    </View>
    
                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.Title}> {data.results[0].hits[0].name.no} </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.Desciption}>{data.results[0].hits[0].description.no}</Text>
                            <Text style={[styles.Text, styles.color]}>{data.results[0].hits[0].potentialPromotionsLabels[5110].text.no}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.Text}> Price: {data.results[0].hits[0].code}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.Text}> Article No: {data.results[0].hits[0].code}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.Text}> EAN: {data.results[0].hits[0].ean}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    };
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        color: {................},
    });
```

queriesContext

```js
    queriesContext.js
    
    import { createContext } from "react";
    
    export const queriesContext = createContext();
```

Error

> ```
> ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: queriesString
>
> This error is located at:
>     in App (created by withDevTools(App))
>     in withDevTools(App)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by AppContainer)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by AppContainer)
>     in AppContainer
>     in main(RootComponent)
>  ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: queriesString
>
> This error is located at:
>     in App (created by withDevTools(App))
>     in withDevTools(App)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by AppContainer)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by AppContainer)
>     in AppContainer
>     in main(RootComponent)
> ```

If anyone could help i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Seems like the problem is with the brackets in the `useContext` call. Change all the brackets to curly braces, e.g. `{queriesString, setQueriesString} = useContext(queriesContext)`

Comment: Thanks, i think this was the issue with the context, but now i got a new error, the context is undefined

Comment: Could you update your sample code and strip it down to the bare minimum while still reproducing your issue? There is too much fluff in your sample code right now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work.

Renamed a few things (queriesString, setQueriesString to query, setQuery) only to make it easier not to misspell.

I changed the brackets to curly braces in `HomeScreen.js` and `GetData.js` as suggested by Fanchen Bao.

In the `HomeScreen.js` from:

```js
export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [ Query, setQuery ] = useContext(queriesContext);
  const [ queries, setQueries ] = useState("0");
```

to:

```js
export default function HomeScreen() {
  const { Query, setQuery } = useContext(queriesContext);
  const [ queries, setQueries ] = useState("0");
```

And in `GetData.js` from:

```js
export default ProductScreen = () => {
  const [ Query ] = useContext(queriesContext);
```

to:

```js
export default ProductScreen = () => {
  const { Query } = useContext(queriesContext);
```

Then in the `App.js`, I added a component and `useState`:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [ Query, setQuery ] = useState("95335");
```

In `GetData`, I had also imported the context from

```js
import { queriesContext } from "./queriesContext";
```

This was wrong and i changed this to the correct path

```js
import { queriesContext } from "../global/queriesContext";
```

After this I still wasn't able to update the context correctly, and i found out that i should use onChangeText instead of onChange in the Textinput.

onChange resulted in the context updating, but the value was not the value in the Textinput field. Instead it was returning [object Object].

> LOG  [object Object]